# change default locale for junit test

Tags: java, junit, internationalization

How do you change the default locale for a JUnit Test. Current locale is en. I want to test for es_ES.
I tried:

```
System.setProperty("locale", "es_ES");
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, and? What code do you run that is locale dependent?

Comment: I didn't get what you exactly meant. I have a few exception messages that needs to be checked. I have created a separate resources file, however, it is not getting linked..

Comment: Hmwell, maybe in this case you want to have a look at [this project](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple); it allows you to get localized messages quite easily

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can set the default `Locale` with [`Locale.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale-).

> Sets the default locale for this instance of the Java Virtual Machine. This does not affect the host locale.

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

Testing with the following resource files:

- test.properties

  ```
  message=Yes
  ```
- test_es_ES.properties

  ```
  message=Sí
  ```

Here is my main function, with no change to my default locale (en_US):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ResourceBundle test = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test");
    System.out.println(test.getString("message"));
}
```

Output:

```
Yes
```

Here is my main function, with a change to your test locale (es_ES):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es", "ES"));
    ResourceBundle test = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test");
    System.out.println(test.getString("message"));
}
```

Output:

```
Sí
```

This should work when applied to a JUnit test case.

Comment: Running JUnits for testing multiple localizations within a test class may lead to improper LocaleContextHolder's Locale value as it internally uses ThreadLocal as mentioned and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204379/spring-localecontextholder-not-correctly-set/65607269#65607269

Comment: The question was about JUnit, where you need the change to be scoped to a single test function, not just changed globally.

Answer (score 1):

[JUnit Pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org/) provides a [`@DefaultLocale`](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/default-locale-timezone/) annotation:

```java
@Test
@DefaultLocale(language = "fr")
void test_with_language() {
    assertEquals("0,1", String.format("%.1f", 0.1));
}
```

For JUnit 4, you can write a [Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules):

```java
public class LocaleRule extends ExternalResource {

    private final Locale testLocale;
    private Locale orginalLocale;

    public LocaleRule(String locale) {
        this.testLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag(locale);
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        orginalLocale = Locale.getDefault();
        Locale.setDefault(testLocale);
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
       Locale.setDefault(orginalLocale);
    };

}
```