# Spring LocaleContextHolder not correctly set

Tags: java, spring, junit, locale

I'm having some issues with Spring `LocaleContextHolder`.

I have the following code:

```
public void sendPasswordRecoverySmsAsync(String phone) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        sendPasswordRecoverySmsSync(phone);
    });
}

public void sendPasswordRecoverySmsSync(String phone) {
    User user = userDao.findByPhone(phone, User.class).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(phone));
    log.info("User found, recovering password");
    user.setUpdateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
    userDao.save(user);

    int otp = codesGenerator.generateOtp(user.getUpdateTime());

    // Sends the SMS.
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    System.out.println("locale " + locale);
    String appName = messageSource.getMessage("app.name", null, locale);
    String smsContent = messageSource.getMessage("sms.password.recovery", new Object[] { otp }, locale);
    Message message = new TextMessage(appName, phone, smsContent);
    try {
        smsClient.submitMessage(message);
    } catch (NexmoClientException | IOException e) {
        log.error("Error while sending recovery password message to phone number [{}]", phone, e);
        throw new UserActivationException("Error while recovering password for user with phone: " + phone, e);
    }
}
```

and this test:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    LocaleContextHolder.resetLocaleContext();
    Mockito.when(tokenGenerator.generateOtp(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(14);
}

@Test(timeout = 3000)
public void testSendPasswordRecoverySmsAsyncError() throws Exception {
    // Mocks.
    LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH, true);
    String mockPhone = "333";
    User mockUser = mockModelBuilder.user(true, true);
    Mockito.when(userDao.findByPhone(mockPhone, User.class)).then(r -> {
        // TODO
        return Optional.of(mockUser);
    });
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ArgumentCaptor<TextMessage> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TextMessage.class);
    Mockito.when(smsClient.submitMessage(messageCaptor.capture())).then(r -> {
        latch.countDown();
        throw new NexmoClientException();
    });

    // Test.
    service.sendPasswordRecoverySmsAsync(mockPhone);
    latch.await();

    // Assertions.
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
    TextMessage actualMessage = messageCaptor.getValue();
    Assert.assertEquals("myApp", actualMessage.getFrom());
    Assert.assertEquals(mockPhone, actualMessage.getTo());
    Assert.assertEquals("Your password recovery code for myApp app is 14", actualMessage.getMessageBody());
}
```

I would expect the ouput of my test being "en" and this works properly if I launch only this one. However, when I run all my tests, the ouput is "it". This is probably either because in other tests I set an ITALIAN locale or because it's getting the system default.

But why is it getting the wrong one even when I'm resetting it explicitly?

Comment: It is set in a thread local, your `getLocale` is running on a different thread, and thus will not see the value set and do a fallback to the default.

Comment: The second flag means that the value should be inherited by child threads. Also, this doesn't explain why it works if I run only the single test

Comment: Yes it does because it is a different thread. If you move the threading it will work. Also make sure you are waiting for the thread to finish, else your teardown (or setup again) might have cleared things before the thread even had a change to run.

Comment: Waiting for the thread to finish is a good catch. Actually I'm using a latch so that should be taken care of. Could you elaborate more on how the threading would affect this? I set the inherit flag to true. This means that even if it's running on a different thread, the value should be inherited from main thread as per Spring documentation. And again, if that's the problem, wouldn't I have the same problem even if I run only the single test?

Comment: If you are using a latch, where are you using it inside `myMethod`? I don't see it. Can you please add the actual code instead of pseudo code, else we start to draw conclusions that might not be correct.

Comment: You're right, I've added the real code now.

Comment: Using inheritable threadlocals is a risk, you easily risk leaking data (as you can see here). Something is  holding on/keeping stuff in a thread local. Why not simply pass the `Locale` into the method, instead of trying to shoehorn it into the `LocaleContextHolder`. Saves you the risk of information and memory leak.

Comment: Because the LocaleContextHolder is managed by Spring. Apart from this test, the real use case is that the Locale is automatically set by Spring and that's why I don't pass it around.

Comment: I know what the `LocaleContextHolder` does and is, however generally speaking using that (or trusting that) in code isn't a good thing. Especially in the case of inheritable thread locals (those are generally a big risk). Hence passing is a lot easier, you will, at some time, run into this issue in production as well. To fix your test, figure out where the `it` is being set and make sure that the `LocaleContextHolder` is cleared after each test.

Comment: Wouldn't the reset on the setup method clear it after (or better at the beginning of) each test?

Comment: No, as it clears for the current thread (and childs of current thread). If another thread has placed something in it it isn't cleared. Such is the nature of `ThreadLocal` and shows the risk with inheritance (if forgotten or properly cleaning ThreadLocals in general). As suggested I would refactor to passing in the `Locale` which makes the code easier and less brittle.

Comment: Actually, you're right. My code is way too brittle. I've changed the code to pass around the variable. Do you want to write down an actual response so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

For solely the purpose of testing such localization cases, you might just need to add the following on your test method. This will essentially mark the context Dirty and recreate it, depending on whether you mention as the context being Dirty either before or After the test execution.

```
@DirtiesContext(methodMode = MethodMode.AFTER_METHOD)
@Test(timeout = 3000)
public void testSendPasswordRecoverySmsAsyncError() throws Exception {...
```

Please refer the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)

Hope this helps, as it resolved a similar problem for me.